# Альтернативное действие для onClick

Tags: html, javascript

Нажатием на ссылку, в текст-бокс "text_01" попадает значение 123

```
<a name="123" onClick="document.getElementById('text_01').value = '123';">123</a>
```

1. Есть ли способ, альтернативный этому, по простоте и действию?
2. По каким-то, не выясненным причинам, все это работало у меня на локальном компьютере, и через неделю, все браузеры кроме IE ничего не делают при нажатии. В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("a[name='123']").click(function(){
    $("#text_01").attr("value", "123");
});
```

Это аналог в jQuery - как видите, гораздо больше кода. Т.о. более громоздко - а значит не подходит. Зато можно абстрагировать на кучу ссылок - тогда может и будет перевес в сторону моего примера. Согласитесь, если ссылок 30(к примеру), то компактнее добавить 3 строчки на jQuery, чем в каждой ссылке писать "onClick".
Вам могу посоветовать добавить "return false;" в обработчик "onClick" - авось поможет ;)

Comment: я тоже "За" использование js библиотек, и разделение html от javascript.. Так и понятнее, и дебагить лучше..

Answer (score 1):

Пример Вы привели не полностью, поэтому ответы будут строиться на догадках.

А вот первая из них: скорее всего у Вас нарушена дом структура (как раз за неделю вы написали еще что-то, что изменило ее, может тег не закрыт где-то). Скорее всего IE более лояльно относится к этому, и поэтому в нем все работает. Может у Вас теперь два дом объекта с таким ИД? Похоже, что имена им раздает автоматом ваш скрипт и поэтому возможен вариант, что еще где-то такое же имя.

Для тестов напишите так:

```
<a name="123" onClick="try{document.getElementById('text_01').value = '123';}catch(e){alert(e.message);}">123</a>
```

А может такого элемента уже и нет (с ид=текст_01)

**Дополнено.**

```
try {
    document.getElementById('text_01').value = '123';
} catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
}
```

Или попробуйте так тогда. Это киньте в функцию и вызовите

```
<script>
function ff() {
    try {
        document.getElementById('text_01').value = '123';
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
} 
</script>
<a name="123" onClick="ff();">123</a>
```

Comment: Теги закрыты все, объект один, имена написаны вручную, и они разные, элемент с ид=текст_01 на месте 8. Опера выдала

>`Cannot convert 'document.getElementById('text_01')' to object`

Мозилла выдала

>`document.getElementById("text_01") is null`

Comment: Судя по ошибкам, у вас нет элемента с id="text_01".

Comment: Хммм. Хмммм2. А ну да, все верно, пробел поставить надо, а то он думает что там объект.
try{  document.getElementById('text_01').value = '123';   }catch(e){   alert(e.message);   }
ИЛИ Попробуй так тогда Это кинь в функцию и вызови ее
<script>
function ff(){
try{  
document.getElementById('text_01').value = '123';   
}catch(e){   
alert(e.message);   
}
}
</script>
<a name="123" onClick="ff();">123</a>
Если повторится ошибка, то кинь код html, разберем

Answer (score 0):

Пишите значение в input type="hidden".
Если не секрет, зачем вам это?

Comment: Эта штука у меня вместо оптион груп.